# Totem: Use --no-existing-session as default

Tags: totem

Is there any way to always automatically use the parameter `--no-existing-session` for Totem? I want to use that parameter whenever I double click on anything that will open Totem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy the global totem.desktop file to your local `applications` folder:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/totem.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Change the line `Exec=totem %U` to `Exec=totem --no-existing-session %U`

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/totem.desktop
   ```

   [image]
3. Save the file and close it. The change should take effect immediately.

Answer (score 0):

## Parameter removed from Totem since Ubuntu 11.10

It seems this parameter doesn't work anymore since 11.10, see [How can I launch multiple instances of Totem since 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/95539/42013)

Be careful when upgrading to *buntu 11.10 if you have your own modified ~/.local/share/applications/totem.desktop because Totem will not open if this parameter is set by default.