# How can I launch multiple instances of Totem since 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, totem, multiple-instances

Since Ubuntu 11.10, I can't use the [`--no-existing-session` parameter](https://askubuntu.com/a/40136) that is used to launch multiple instances of Totem, because it has been removed from [newest versions of Totem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/595897).

Is there a new way to do that now? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. But as doug mentioned you need to change some lines of code.

If you are running ubuntu quantal you can use my ppa. I build a totem version which includes that `--no-existing-session` command.

You can find packages here:

https://launchpad.net/~qos/+archive/totem

Answer (score 3):

Simple - you can't, at least not without altering the source code. Vlc is an option if you have need to run multiple instances.

As far as 2 totem instances  - the only way I see is to use 2 different versions of totem, here I continue to keep a self-built totem-xine around, in that case both can run at the same time

[image: currently on 12.04]

Answer (score 1):

One possible escape from the limitation is to use two/multiple user accounts - which each allows for one instance...

Though not very correct from the "safety/permissions/security" point of view one could do the following command

`xhost +x; sudo bash -c "totem &"`

(the command is used in the terminal of the active user, no need to do any logout/user switch at all)

which will run another totem instance under under the root-user. This arguably is a major security concern, but still maybe ok for listening to *.ogg *.mp3 in rare occasions.
Also it would be smart to check for a safer substitution to the `xhost +` command to allow the x-server access in a more restricted manner.

The mehtod of using two/multiple user accounts can be a workaround to the limitation of only one instance per user. maybe a smart person can even create a kind of sandboxing "on-the-fly-user-creation" script which will call a totem instance. Which then could be hopefully less a concern then using the **root** account.

Comment: There is only a *very* thin security barrier between root and user: All a virus has to do to elevate privileges is wait for the next time you run `sudo` and grab your password.

Answer (score 0):

Based on humanityANDpeace's answer:

```
sudo -u ${USERNAME} totem &
```

works as well, but without the security risks.